# Blocked by CORS al utilizar flipbook pdf con turn.js y pdf.js

Tags: php, javascript, cors, jspdf

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto PHP en el cual tengo que visualizar los pdf en formato flipbook, para esto trato los pdf con turn.js y pdf.js, y para eso me baso en el ejemplo propuesto por [MaximS](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/89), verán el aplicativo funciona y todo cuando el pdf se encuentra en local, pero al tratar de traer el pdf desde otro sitio me genera el siguiente error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/documento/django-es.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

No importa si tengo en local o en servidor siempre me genera este error de la CORS, y he modificado el .htaccess del sitio B con el pdf para que en el origin me permita desde mi sitio A y aun asi no me lo permite el CORS.

Este lo presenta directamente la librería pdf.js ya que es la que no logra pasar las cors policy, mediante el cors-anywhere puedo enviarlas, pero adquirir un servidor nodejs no es viable, el problema se encuentra centrado en la libreria pdfjs, que es la que no puede obtener el pdf de un servidor ajeno al mio, al tratar de enviar un pdf por ejemplo http://cotana.informatica.edu.bo/downloads/ld-Ingenieria.de.software.enfoque.practico.7ed.Pressman.PDF me genera el problema de la cors.

Alguien podría ayudarme en dar solucion a esto, estoy literalmente apunto de llorar sangre.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, si bien en la respuesta de esa pregunta explican en detalles lo que es la cors, la solución planteada para este proyecto es acceder al servidor A donde se encuentran los pdf, ahora bien, no se si logre a explicar bien el error, pero este lo presenta directamente la librería pdf.js ya que es la que no logra pasar las cors policy, mediante el cors-anywhere puedo enviarlas, pero adquirir un servidor nodejs no es viable, y aunque en la pregunta que citas dan una idea de como solucionar, mi problema se encuentra directamente en la librería y no se como realmente aplicar en ella

Comment: Comprendo, si puedes explicar eso que pones en el comentario, editando tu pregunta, podría retirar el voto de cierre. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para editarla. Haré algunas pruebas y trataré de reproducir tu problema. Saludos